# Motivation for defining a functions codomain

Tags: functions, definition

Why not always refer to a functions image, what is the point in specifying some super set of that image and then naming that super set the functions "codomain"? What does explicitly defining a set that contains more values for which your function does not even output add to the definition of a function.

Comment: Related to / somewhat of a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5480/148175, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/97390/148175,
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/777563/148175

Comment: Pragmatically, if I don't know the precise range but I still want to give a generic description of the values of the function the concept of a codomain is useful. That said, there is much more in the links above...

Comment: It is a way of identifying surjectivity (a function that is onto)...it is equivalent that the range (image) and codomain are the same

Comment: @afedder So we define the notion of a codomain, so we can define another notion of surjectivity. Why is that helpful?

Comment: Suppose I want to discuss the function $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^7 \sin x + e^{\cos x}.$ I may want to do various things like find its derivative or its roots. I can try to do these things without going to lengthy trouble of finding its precise image, which is really irrelevant to me. Finding the range can be tiresome, or extremely difficult. The point of giving the codomain is to give *some* information about the values, and so we have a precise idea of what type of objects we are dealing with.

Comment: @Ethan this is not the sole purpose of defining a codomain, there are many, I was only citing one use. Another one is as just referenced above dealing with the complications of computing ranges of functions...sometimes this is very simple, but other times it is quite tedious and maybe no need.