# 'Function may not necessarily use all elements of specified range'?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

In a textbook on the theory of computation, I encountered a passage which states:

> The outputs of a function come from a set called its **range**... In the case of the function abs, if we are working with integers, the domain and the range are Z... *Note that a function may not necessarily use all the elements of the specified range.*

Italics mine. I had always thought that range was the set of all elements mapped by the function from the set of all elements in the domain, so that if an element cannot be obtained by being mapped from the domain by the function, then it is not in the range. In the example above, I thought that the range was { x: x in Z, x >= 0 }. I understand how the range can be further restricted by definition in the function, but I don't understand how the term 'range' has any meaning if it can encompass more elements than can actually be mapped from the domain by the function. Could anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Your definition is generally called the *image* of a function.  The textbook you cite is describing what is more precisely called the *codomain* of a function.  The word "range" is a little ambiguous, in that it can take either of these meanings depending on the context; my impression is that it generally means "image" these days, so you're more up-to-date than the textbook.

Comment: What you mean is the *image* of the function. The *range* (and domain) are used to define the function in the first place (and you *could* define abs as map $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb N_0$ as well as as a map $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ if you wish). Only after a successfull definition of your function, you can contemplate what the image is (which may or may not be strictly smaller). As the text says, the range is where the output *comes from*, it may not be exhausted this way.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5480/how-is-the-codomain-for-a-function-defined